# Is deleting an intermediate node in single linked list done in O(1)?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

Suppose, we need to delete an intermediate node in LL and pointer to that node is given, which is to be deleted.

But, i can delete that node in O(1) as pointer is given to that node, but in order to make entry of node before deleted node to the node which is after the deleted node, i need to traverse upto that element which is O(N).

**So, How can this complexity be made O(1) overall. Can this be done always or only in some conditions ?**

Answer (score 2):

When using a linked list, if this scenario is often encountered then a different deletion algorithm is used. Instead of adjusting pointers for deletion, you can insert a flag to the link list element and mark them deleted. Then you ignore the records with *deleted* flag. Such a deletion is O(1).

Other kinds of implementations might also provide better deletion costs. But your analysis on the general case is correct. If you have only a single link for each node and there is no other improvement, then deletion is O(n).

Comment: First one is a interesting solution. Would be great to know what could be its cons?

Comment: One definite downside is if there are frequent insertions and deletions than the list gets too long due to ignored entries with deleted flag. You need to compact the list by deleting the deleted nodes every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have this linked list:

```
A->B->C->D->E
```

As we know A has the pointer to B and B has that to C and so on. Lets say, you know the pointer to C and intend to delete it. The new list should be:

```
A->B->D->E
```

Here, B and D are to be linked. Obviously You can obtain address of D from C's next pointer. Yes we have the address of C , but that ***does not mean that you necessarily know the pointer of B***. So, you need to traverse from the head upto the node (B) which will have the pointer to C. **This accounts for the O(n) complexity as it is dependent on the number of nodes 'n' in the linked list**. Once you have spotted B, you can assign D's address to its next pointer. And thus, C is deleted from the linked list.

*The complexity can be made O(1) if you know the address of the node prior to the node that is to be deleted (In above case node B).*

Answer (score 0):

Well, I remember one "solution" where you don't actually delete that particular node (Let's call It "B Node") to which you have pointer, but what you do is copy the data of "next" node (lets Call it "C Node") into the "B Node" and then delete the "C" node in this way you have O(1) Complexity.

A->B->C

```
  copy data from C to B . Delete C.
```